# How to accept LibreOffice Calc autocomplete suggestion without leaving the cell edit mode?

Tags: openoffice, autocomplete, libreoffice, openoffice-calc

Whenever I start typing a sentence in a LibreOfice Calc cell it suggests autocomplete options based on other cells contents. I usually would like to accept it and make a slight modification but when I press Enter to accept it exits the cell and I have to use mouse to start editing it again. Can I accept an autocomplete suggestion without finalizing editing?

Answer (score 6):

Just tap <kbd>F2</kbd> to accept the suggested AutoComplete content and continue to edit.

After filling A1:A3 with a couple of cities, I started typing *Se* in A4 and Calc makes a suggestion.

[image: Accepting AutoComplete content]

I tap <kbd>F2</kbd> and the AutoComplete content is inserted leaving me with an active edit cursor at the end of the inserted content.

[image: Accepting AutoComplete content]

The bonus to this behavior is that you are also transferred into `INSRT` edit mode where the arrow keys can be used to navigate within the string.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>F2</kbd> doesn't work to autocomplete functions; but <kbd>Enter</kbd> does.

If you already have values in a `SUM(x,y)` but you want to change to `SUBTOTAL`, nothing short of typing it all out seems to work sadly. (LIBRE 4.4)

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question (which is referring to text **not** functions.)

Comment: @DavidPostill - Even if you are right, and just as a side note, due to what Google brings as results this answer was useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you type the name in a formula, after the first few characters entered you will see the entire name as a tip.
[image]

Press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in order to accept the name from the tip.

If more than one name starts with the same characters, you can scroll forward through all the names using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> keys and backward using the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> keys.

[src](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.4/en-US/text/scalc/guide/value_with_name.html?DbPAR=CALC)